# PHP xDebug graph interpretation

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug, kcachegrind

I am profiling a PHP application (built upon the Zend framework). Attached you can find a screenshot of the main call graph that KCacheGrind produces from xDebug output.

There are two things that I don't understand:

1) Why does `{main}` *"fork"* into 2 calls? Are they supposed to be parallel somehow or does one happen after the other?

2) The arrow to the left of `{main}` has a little blue bar with the text `2x`; does this mean that the call to `Zend_Application->bootstrap` happened twice?

[image: PHP xDebug graph]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. The calls (of course) happen after each other. The graph splits because each of the top two functions are *called* by main(). The graph shows calls, not execution order.
2. Yes, that's exactly what it means. main() called Zend_Application->bootstrap twice and ->run once.